# How can I put an editable table view in a tab bar application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller, interface-builder

I am starting out with the tab bar application in XCode and I want to put a table view in one of the tabs. I know how to physically put the table view into a tab with interface builder, but I need to be able to edit the data in the table, so I'm not just left with blank cells.

So, how can I edit the data in the table?

Essentially, I want to put a navigation-based application inside the tab of a tab bar application.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableViewCells don't, by themselves, support the ability for the user to edit their content.  You can set up your UI to allow users to do so, but it'll take a little extra effort.

If what you're really looking for is for the user to be able to enter text into a table cell, I would add an Edit button to your text cells, so that the user can tap it to go into edit mode for a cell.

When a cell goes into edit mode, add a UITextField to the cell view and call its -makeFirstResponder method to bring up the keyboard.

When the user taps the Done button on the keyboard, call -resignFirstResponder on the text field to dismiss the keyboard, then update your table view's data source object (this is the object you've assigned to the UITableView's dataSource property) with the string from the text field's text property and remove the UITextField from your table cell and reload the table's data by calling its reloadData method.  Or if you are keeping a reference to the edited table cell somewhere, you could just update the cell object directly instead of calling reloadData on the table.

Comment: Sorry - I think the question wasn't clear. I'll submit another question. Thank you for the help, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just add text to table cells in InterfaceBuilder.  You'll need to hook your UITableView to a UITableViewDataSource, and have that data source provide the cells you want your table to display.

Here's a great starting point:  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAPIOverview/TableViewAPIOverview.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH4-SW2

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I was looking for a method of how to actually do this. Do you think you could tell me what files I would need to make and what code I would need to write? I don't want you to waste your time actually writing the code out, but a list of steps would be good.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot http://www.amasso.info/?p=77